# Change Background-Color of jQuery Autocomplete Drop Down When Using Arrow Keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [jQuery Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default) in my project, and want the background color of the suggested items to be red when I either hover my mouse over it, or use the up/down arrow keys to select one.

So far my code looks like this:

```
<input id="ajax" placeholder="Search by company name or ticker" autofocus method="GET"  action="{% url 'index' %}" >

<script>
    var availableTags = [
        {% for stock in stocks %}
            { value: "/s/{{ stock.ticker|safe }}",
              label: "{{ stock.ticker|safe }} - {{ stock.name|safe }}"
            },
        {% endfor %}    
    ];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input#ajax").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            select: function( event, ui ) { 
                window.location.href = ui.item.value;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am able to edit the background color of the mouse over using the following code, but it still defaults to the generic blue when I use the arrow keys to make a selection:

```
    .ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
        color: #303030;
        background-color: #fff;
    }        

    .ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper:hover {
        color: #303030;
        background-color: red;
        border: #fff 1px solid;
    }
```

I am a bit new to Javascript and an absolute beginner at jQuery, any ideas on how I can get the background color to be consistent whether using the mouse or arrow keys to make a selection? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper:hover {
    color: #303030;
    background-color: red;
    border: #fff 1px solid;
}
```

To this:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper:hover, .ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
    color: #303030;
    background-color: red;
    border: #fff 1px solid;
}
```

When you move on to an autocomplete item, jQuery-UI adds the `.ui-state-active` class to the `div` inside the `li` (the one with the `.ui-menu-item-wrapper` class), and when you move off of it, it removes the class again.

As a general rule, jQuery-UI uses this technique of toggling the `ui-state-active` class on and off when you move to and from items via the keyboard. Since in some cases the item doesn't "officially" receive focus, the `:focus` pseudoclass isn't completely reliable for this purpose (and indeed, it doesn't work here).

I can see why you had trouble finding this. Every time you try to inspect the item you've arrow-keyed down to, the item loses focus so you can't see what its state is! Anyway, the `ui-state-active` class is something to keep an eye out for when you're trying to style some sort of selected item in jQuery-UI.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];

  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  color: #303030;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper:hover,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
  color: #303030;
  background-color: red;
  border: #fff 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```